# Can not Create HDInsight Cluster in Azure within Virtual Network

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-virtual-network

I try to create a HDInsight Storm Cluster in Azure and add it to my Virtual Network. But for some reason I always got the following error message:

> Pre cluster creation validation failed: Virtual network validation failed for cluster xxxxxxx due to user errorValidation Report: User subscription 
>                               xxxxxxx doesn't have any virtual network. Exception:

The Powershell Scripts looks as follows:

```
####################################
# Set these variables
####################################
$nameToken = "xxxxxx" 

$httpUserName = "xxxxxx"  
$httpPassword = "xxxxxx" 

$ClusterTyp = "Storm"
$namePrefix = $nameToken.ToLower()

$resourceGroupName = $namePrefix
$hdinsightClusterName = $namePrefix +"storm"
$defaultStorageAccountName = $namePrefix +"storm"
$defaultBlobContainerName = $hdinsightClusterName

$location = "North Europe"
$clusterSizeInNodes = 1

#Virtual Network
$NetworkName  = "xxxxxx"
$subnetName = "xxxxxx"

# Treat all errors as terminating
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

###########################################
# Connect to Azure
###########################################
#region - Connect to Azure subscription
Write-Host "`nConnecting to your Azure subscription ..." -ForegroundColor Green
try{Get-AzureRmContext}
catch{Login-AzureRmAccount}
#endregion

###########################################
# Preapre default storage account and container
###########################################
New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $defaultStorageAccountName -Type Standard_GRS -Location $location

$defaultStorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $defaultStorageAccountName).Key1


$defaultStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $defaultStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $defaultStorageAccountKey
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $hdinsightClusterName -Context $defaultStorageContext 

###########################################
# Create the cluster
###########################################

$vnet = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $NetworkName).Id
$httpPW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $httpPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$httpCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($httpUserName,$httpPW)
Write-Host "Create HDInsight Cluster" -ForegroundColor Yellow

New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ClusterName $hdinsightClusterName -Location $location -ClusterSizeInNodes $clusterSizeInNodes -ClusterType $ClusterTyp -OSType Windows -Version "3.2" -HttpCredential $httpCredential -DefaultStorageAccountName "$defaultStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" -DefaultStorageAccountKey $defaultStorageAccountKey -DefaultStorageContainer $hdinsightClusterName  -VirtualNetworkId $vnet -SubnetName $subnetName

Write-Host "HDInsight Cluster Created" -ForegroundColor Green
####################################
# Verify the cluster
####################################
Get-AzureRmHDInsightCluster -ClusterName $hdinsightClusterName
```

If I run the Script without the following parameters it seems to work properly:

> -VirtualNetworkId $vnet -SubnetName $subnetName

Of course, the Cluster will not be added to the Virtual Network without those parameters.
The virtual Network exists for sure, if I add the Cluster manually in the portal, i'm able to add it to the corresponding Virtual Network.

Thanks already for your help.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier using an ARM template. You can call ARM template from the portal, Azure PowerShell or CLI.  Here is a sample creating a HBase cluster within a virtual network.  You can easily modified the template to create a storm cluster instead:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hbase-provision-vnet/

Please note:

Windows-based clusters require a v1 (Classic) Virtual Network, while Linux-based clusters require a v2 (Azure Resource Manager,) Virtual Network. If you do not have the correct type of network, it will not be usable when you create the cluster. See https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network/

Comment: Cool perfect, works great with the ARM template!
Thanks a lot!